# I want to return a specific list when I have a collection of lists

Tags: python

I want to return a specific list, when I have a collection of lists, but I am not to sure how to do this. I tried this approach but it didn't work. Any ideas

```
this_list1 = [2,3,4,5]
this_list2 = [5,6,9,8]

x = input("which list do you want")

print this_list(x)
```

Comment: What is your desired process, ie give a sample input and output please.

Comment: If you have a collection of lists, why not make it a proper collection? Put them in a dictionary like `all_lists = { 'list 1': [2, 3, 4, 5], 'list 2': [5, 6, 9, 8] }` and then return `all_lists[x]` if it exists.

Comment: You can do like @kaya3 suggested or just use a simple `if` block if you have only two lists to deal with.

Comment: This is unclear, and seems to be horribly lacking in effort overall. Also, is there any particular reason why you’re using Python 2?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a list that contains both of your lists.

```py
this_list1 = [2,3,4,5]
this_list2 = [5,6,9,8]

big_list = [this_list1, this_list2]

f = int(input("which list do you want")) # 0

print(big_list[f])
```

```
Out[9]: [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list of lists, or other structures better than just having similar names is recommended definitely, but for the sake of argument it can still be done with the requested input:

```
this_list1 = [2,3,4,5]
this_list2 = [5,6,9,8]
x = input("which list do you want")
print(locals()['this_list' + str(x)])
```